# Using Tidyverse pipeline to count NAs and reorder

Tags: r, tidyverse

I want to create a vector of the count of `NAs` for each column in a data set and then reorder it to show the columns with the largest missing values at the top and then decreasing. I've done the following, which works:

```
na_vector <- household_data %>% summarise_all(list(~(sum(is.na(.))))) 
na_vector <- as.vector(na_vector)
sort(na_vector, decreasing = T)
```

But there must be a way to do this all within the `tidyverse` pipeline, right? How would I do this?

Comment: You should post a reproducible example to get a real answer, but something like lapply(household_data, function(x) sum(is.na(x)) would be a good start

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Example Data***

```
set.seed(123)
mat <- matrix(round(rnorm(50), 2), 10, 5)
mat[sample(1:50, 20)] <- NA
df <- data.frame(mat)

#       X1    X2    X3    X4    X5
# 1  -0.56  1.22 -1.07    NA    NA
# 2  -0.23    NA    NA    NA -0.21
# 3     NA  0.40    NA  0.90    NA
# 4   0.07    NA -0.73  0.88    NA
# 5   0.13 -0.56    NA    NA  1.21
# 6   1.72  1.79 -1.69  0.69    NA
# 7     NA  0.50  0.84  0.55    NA
# 8  -1.27 -1.97  0.15 -0.06    NA
# 9  -0.69  0.70    NA -0.31  0.78
# 10 -0.45 -0.47    NA    NA    NA
```

**1. `base` solution**

```
sort(colSums(is.na(df)), decreasing = T)

# X5 X3 X4 X1 X2 
#  7  5  4  2  2
```

**2. `dplyr` pipes**

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  summarise(across(everything(), ~ sum(is.na(.)))) %>%
  unlist %>% sort(decreasing = T)

# X5 X3 X4 X1 X2 
#  7  5  4  2  2
```

**3.** A complex way but with more `tidyverse` logic

```
df %>%
  summarise(across(everything(), ~ sum(is.na(.)))) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(everything()) %>%
  arrange(desc(value)) %>% 
  deframe()

# X5 X3 X4 X1 X2 
#  7  5  4  2  2
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a sample dataset to play around with your question.  Here is the dataset I am using:

```
    library(tidyverse)

options <- c("Yes", "No", NA_character_)

# create the first row of the df that we will be recreating
df <- tibble(
  ID = 1,
  neckpain = "Yes",
  backpain = NA_character_,
  kneepain = NA_character_,
)

# create a function that will help build the entire reproducible df
add.option.sample.row.f <- function( df, n ){
  # FUNCTION add.option.sample.row.f
  # args: df as tibble
  #       n  as integer
  # takes df and adds options to it randomly
  # returns a 4 by n(plus nrow(df)) df of
  # ID (unique), neckpain (charcter),
  # backpain (charcter), kneepain (charcter)
  # - - - - - - - - -- - - - - - - - - - - --
  for( i in 1:n ){ 
    df <- df %>% add_row(
      ID = nrow(df)+1,
      neckpain = sample(options)[1],
      backpain = sample(options)[1],
      kneepain = sample(options)[1]
    )
  }
  return(df)
}

# build sample df
df <- add.option.sample.row.f(df, 500)

head(df)
# A tibble: 6 x 4
# ID neckpain backpain kneepain
# <dbl> <chr>    <chr>    <chr>   
# 1     1 Yes      NA       NA      
# 2     2 Yes      NA       Yes     
# 3     3 No       NA       Yes     
# 4     4 NA       NA       NA      
# 5     5 NA       No       NA      
# 6     6 NA       Yes      Yes
```

With this data set lets approach what you are looking to do.  First lets take the questionable columns as a vector:

```
columns.to.reorder <- c(
  "neckpain",
  "backpain",
  "kneepain"
)
```

Use mutate to find the cumsum of all na's.

```
    df %>%
  mutate(
  !!paste0("NA_", columns.to.reorder[1]) := cumsum(is.na(.[[columns.to.reorder[1]]])+0),
  !!paste0("NA_", columns.to.reorder[2]) := cumsum(is.na(.[[columns.to.reorder[2]]])+0),
  !!paste0("NA_", columns.to.reorder[3]) := cumsum(is.na(.[[columns.to.reorder[3]]])+0)
  )
```

Or use the more elegant "across" argument of the newer dplyr

```
df %>% 
  mutate(across(.cols = columns.to.reorder,
         .fns = function(x)cumsum(is.na(x)),
         .names =  "{col}.{fn}")
  )
```

This will make it easier to find the MAX of each column's na's, as the cumsum will tic each additional na as they occur.  I do not know how you'd like to split the vectors out as each vector's sort would resort the other vectors.  Please advise the direction you are going with this.